# PHP cUrl Handle resource is replaced by an integer

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm using **PHP curl** to send a series of requests to a 3rd party server which requires login and then persisting the session cookie for that login.

So I wrapped the curl operation into this class:

```
class SoapCli {
    private $ch;
    private $id;
    private $rc;

    function __construct() {
        $this->rc=0;
        $this->id=bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        $time=microtime(true);
        error_log(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Instance id $this->id created ($time): \$this->ch = ".print_r($this->ch,true).PHP_EOL,3,"log.txt");
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    }

    function Request(string $method, string $url, array $headers = array(), $postdata = "", $referer = null) {
        $resp = new stdClass();
        $resp->id = $this->id;
        $this->rc++;
        $time=microtime(true);
        error_log("Instance id $this->id before request $this->rc ($time): \$this->ch = ".print_r($this->ch,true).PHP_EOL,3,"log.txt");
        try {
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            if (isset($referer)) curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
            if (preg_match("/^POST$/i",$method)===1) curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
            $resp->body = curl_exec($this->ch);
            $resp->err_message = curl_error($this->ch);
            $resp->err_number = curl_errno($this->ch);
            $resp->info = curl_getinfo($this->ch);
        }
        catch (Exception $exception) {
            $resp->err_message = $exception->getMessage();
            $resp->err_number = $exception->getCode();
            $resp->info = $exception->getTrace();
        }
        $time=microtime(true);
        error_log("Instance id $this->id before request $this->rc ($time): \$this->ch = ".print_r($this->ch,true).PHP_EOL,3,"log.txt");
        return $resp;
    }
}
```

However, after the 3rd request, the protected variable that stored the curl handle resource has its content replaced by the value of **0 (integer)** and I really can't figure out why. I could only collect this log:

```
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd created (1547852391.7976): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 1 (1547852391.8025): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 1 (1547852392.0723): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 2 (1547852392.0778): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 2 (1547852392.357): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 3 (1547852392.3616): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 3 (1547852392.6225): $this->ch = Resource id #3
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 4 (1547852393.0264): $this->ch = 0
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 4 (1547852393.0758): $this->ch = 0
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 5 (1547852394.8992): $this->ch = 0
Instance id 1cb893bc5b7369bd before request 5 (1547852394.9461): $this->ch = 0
```

**EDIT:** This is the code that consumes class `SoapCli`:

```
// index.php

$postdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"]===true) {
    echo file_get_contents("main.html");
} else if (isset($postdata) && isset($postdata["action"])) {
    $action = $postdata["action"];
    if ($action==="Login" && isset($postdata["usrcpf"]) && isset($postdata["usrpwd"])) {
        $username=$postdata["username"];
        $password=$postdata["password"];
        $sc=new SoapCli();   //instantiated here
        $_SESSION["sc"]=$sc;
        $login_response = $sc->Request(
            "GET",
            BASEURL."/login",
            array(
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0",
                "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
                "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
                )
            );
        if ($login_response->err_number) {
            echo file_get_contents("login_server_error.html");
        } else {
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $dom->loadHTML($login_response->body);
            $xdom  = new DOMXPath($dom);
            $csrf_token_nodes = $xdom->query("//input[@name='_csrf_token']/@value");
            if ($csrf_token_nodes->length<1) {
                echo file_get_contents("login_server_error.html");
            } else {
                $csrf_token = $csrf_token_nodes->item(0)->textContent;
                $postdata = "_csrf_token=$csrf_token&_username=$username&_password=$password&_submit=Login";
                $login_check_response = $sc->Request(
                    "POST",
                    BASEURL."/login_check",
                    array(
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0",
                        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Connection: keep-alive",
                        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
                    ),
                    $postdata,
                    BASEURL."/login"
                    );
                if ($login_check_response->err_number) {
                    echo file_get_contents("login_server_error.html");
                } elseif (strpos($login_check_response->body, "api.js")) {
                    echo file_get_contents("login_auth_error.html");
                } else {
                    $route_userinfo = $sc->Request(
                        "POST",
                        BASEURL."/route",
                        array(
                             "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0",
                             "Accept: */*",
                             "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
                             "Content-Type: application/json",
                             "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
                             "Connection: keep-alive",
                             "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
                         ),
                        USERINFO_JSON,
                        BASEURL."/"
                        );
                    if ($route_userinfo->err_number) {
                        echo file_get_contents("login_server_error.html");
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION["logged_in"]=true;
                        $_SESSION["user_info"]=json_decode($route_userinfo->body);
                        header("Location: ".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], true, 303);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
    }
} else {
    echo file_get_contents("login.html");
}
```

and

```
// ajax.php (called by JS in main.html, which is loaded after login)

if ($_SESSION["logged_in"]===true) {
    $postdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        if (isset($postdata["content"])) {
            if ($postdata["content"]==="tasks") {
                $sc=$_SESSION["sc"];
                $route_tasks = $sc->Request(
                    "POST",
                    BASEURL."/route",
                    array(
                         "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0",
                         "Accept: */*",
                         "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
                         "Content-Type: application/json",
                         "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
                         "Connection: keep-alive",
                         "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
                     ),
                    TAKS_JSON,
                    BASEURL."/"
                    );
                if ($route_tasks->err_number) {
                    echo file_get_contents("ajax_server_error.html");
                } else {
                    $tarefas=json_decode($route_tasks->body);
                    if (isset($tarefas) && is_array($tarefas->records)) {
                        foreach($tarefas->records as $i=>$tarefa){
                            echo "<p>".$tarefa->especieTarefa->nome."</p>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        http_response_code(500);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            http_response_code(400);
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
}
```

Since the variable `SoapCli::ch` is not accessible out of the class, I really can't see how its content could be changed without a statement. I coundn't find any information about a kind of http request/response which would destroy the handle, either.

### Additional info

Whatever it is, it doesn't have to do with the request, because i tried to repeat request #3, which is valid and receives a valid response, and its repetition fails because of the handle is gone.

Plus, what I'm trying to implement in PHP is already done by a fully functional .NET desktop (winforms) application, so it's not like it can't be done for external reasons. I'm just trying to do with PHP curl what I did with `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`, and stumbled upon the problem described at this post.

How can I preserve the handle as long as I need it?

I'm using PHP 7.2 on IIS Express/Windows 10.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the actual code you're running? The code says `New SoapCli instance` but your log message says just `created`.

Comment: I changed only the text of the log

Comment: Protected properties can be accessed and modified in subclasses, that's the difference between protected and private. Do you have any subclasses of `SoapCli`?

Comment: No, only that one Class

Comment: What happens if you change it to private?

Comment: I'll try that and get back with the answer

Comment: Nothing different happens. @Barmar, **I edited the post** to update my code and the log upon your previous observation.

Comment: If this is really all the code of the class, I don't see any way it can happen other than a serious PHP bug. Variables don't change values on their own.

Comment: I swear it is all the code... I made the class exactly to seal the curl variable because it was hitting my nerve before that.

Comment: Don't turn off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`

Comment: Try setting `curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);` and output `curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`, maybe curl is closing after a failure. Im not so sure that a try catch block actually works with curl

Comment: @Solrac Even if curl closes, how would that change the value of `$this->ch`?

Comment: Because `0 == false` is true, hell I think even `null == false` is true

Comment: So you can try `var_dump()` or `var_export()` instead of `print_r()` as well

Comment: @Solrac, no changes after implementing your suggestion of `curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);` and if I change `print_r` for `var_export`, it printis `$this->ch = NULL` until request #3 and `$this->ch = 0`thereafter.

Comment: Are you getting `http 200` on every call that has a resource?

Comment: Yes, 200 from #1 to #3, and the request isn't even sent after that.

Comment: You aren't including all the code, because there's no use of the class you've defined. And what do you think that `try` block is going to `catch`?

Comment: @miken32, I ommited the use of the class for the sake of brevity: it's constructed with no parameters, then call these resources the same server: 1. `GET /login' (receives text/html); 2. `POST /login_check` (sends application/x-www-form-urlencoded user name and password, receives text/html); 3. `POST /route` (sends application/json parameters, receives tex/html); 4. `POST /route` (sends application/json parameters, receives tex/html); etc. #3 and #4 are similar but the handle vanishes after successful #3. As for `try` block, I wanted to catch whatever was happening, but got nothing.

Comment: @Dharman, you're right, I'll set up the proper "cacerts.pem" before moving to production, **if I can overcome the issue of this post**.

Comment: It is impossible for me to replicate your situation, I was able to make 100 calls using a for loop without an issue, all using GET to the same page. Can you provide the code you are using to consume this class?

Comment: @Solrac, there you have it. I'm not allowed to provide actual urls and login info, though. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: **the handle does not exist when you are trying to use it inside ajax.php**

Inside `ajax.php`, take a look at the following line:

```
                $sc=$_SESSION["sc"];
```

And then you call:

```
                $route_tasks = $sc->Request(
                   ...
                    );
```

So you instaciated your class inside `index.php` and all the 3 calls made there where succesfull, then you write an object into the `$_SESSION["sc"]` variable and apparently the object gets encoded and decoded correctly by php's session handler which is why you are still able to call the method `Request` inside `ajax.php` after retrieving the object.

While you are indeed using an object in `ajax.php` it is not the same instance of the object that was created by `index.php` as that instance belongs to the `index.php` thread along with the `curl` handle; calling `ajax.php` from `index.php` will create a diffrent thread to handle it and will require a new `curl` handle as well.

Change `$sc=$_SESSION["sc"];` to `$sc=new SoapCli();` so the `curl` handle can be created before used.

Comment: Hi, @Solrac, thank you. I understand what you say. I made a workaround by setting a cookie file with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and rebuilding the handle everytime it was gone and it started working, and it makes sense with your explanation.

There's something puzzling me, however. How can there be another instance of SoapCli in ajax.php, if the constructor wasn't called? Because if it was, then there would be a new handle, and it would fail because of the lack of the session cookie (acquired by the first instance)...

Comment: `$_SESSION["sc"]` it's holding an already constructed copy of the original object. For this copy a constructor is never called; the object was retrieved from session storage and built on `session_start()` and this is why, everytime a new php script fires up this object will lack of a `curl`  handle. It is unusual to use session storage as a class transport tho.

Comment: I'm a rookie in PHP and Web development, but now I undesrtand why it is unusual to store constructed objects in session variables. They could become zombies like in this case. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: My pleasure @VbobCat I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer just to show how I went around the problem that was described and explained by @Solrac in his answer (which is correct and I'll accept):

```
class SoapCli {
    private $ch;
    private $cookiepot;

    function __construct() {
        $this->cookiepot=tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),"CookieJar");
        $this->reconstruct();
    }

    function reconstruct() {
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookiepot);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookiepot);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 32);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    }

    function Request(string $method, string $url, array $headers = array(), $postdata = "", $referer = "") {
        if (!is_resource($this->ch)) {
            $this->reconstruct();
        }
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        if (preg_match("/^POST$/i",$method)===1) curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        $response=curl_exec($this->ch);
        list($headers,$body)=preg_split("/\r\n\r\n(?!HTTP)/", $response, 2);
        $resp_obj = (object) array(
            "body"=>$body,
            "headers"=>$headers,
            "err_number"=>curl_errno($this->ch),
            "err_message"=>curl_error($this->ch),
            "info"=>curl_getinfo($this->ch)
        );
        return $resp_obj;
    }

    function log(string $text) {
        file_put_contents($this->id."log.txt",$text.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND|FILE_TEXT|LOCK_EX);
    }
}
```